# Bootstrap box news doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

this simple Bootstrap code works correctly only on Firefox; I don't find the error?

On Chrome and Safari the text it's not shown (only images) and there is a big margin.

```
 <div class="row">


      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">

      <div class="media">
       <a class="pull-left" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/157/big.jpg" alt="abc abc">
       </a>
       <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Media heading</a></h4>
          This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
          This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
          This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
          This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>


      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">

      <div class="media">
       <a class="pull-left" href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/155/big.jpg" alt="abc abc">
       </a>
       <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Media heading</a></h4>
          This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
          This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
          This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
          This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: here the example from official site: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media-default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at how the Bootstrap grid system works (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

You can see a working example here: http://www.bootply.com/128356

```
<div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
       <img class="media-object img-responsive" src="/img/157/big.jpg" alt="abc abc">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
       <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
       This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
       This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
       This is some sample text. This is some sample text. 
       This is some sample text. This is some sample text.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jacob. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include an explanation with code to help with understanding the solution.